# HTTP or HTTPS according to current connection

Tags: javascript, html, http, https

Whats the best way to determine if user is on HTTP or HTTPS connection on specific page without usage of server-side dynamic language?

I have a page with form, which posts to some URL and I would like that URL to be HTTP or HTTPS - according to current connection.

Perhaps there's some solution like:

```
<form action="://www.mysite/form/post" method="post">
```

which would set HTTP or HTTPs accordingly.

If that's impossible to set with just HTML, whats the best way to do it with javascript?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly there :)

it's

```
//www.mysite.com/form/post
```

[More about protocol relative URLs](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)

However, as @Petra mentioned, of course this makes sense only when the target is on a different domain. Otherwise, you would just use normal relative URLS: `/form/post`